Error: Unable to locate package anbox-modules-dkms
When running the command sudo apt upgrade a message appears
Unable to locate package anbox-modules-dkms


From the Anbox Github page:

The Anbox project was once ago created in 2017 to bring Android to any Linux based desktop operating system. It's development has however stalled in the past years and it's only fair to say that now in 2023 it's no longer actively developed.

TL;DR: The Anbox project is dead.
Furthermore, it states there are 2 other options:

If you're looking for a solution to run Android on your Linux desktop:

Waydroid is rebuilding the original idea behind Anbox with explicit focus on modern Wayland powered desktop environments.

If you're looking for a solution to run Android in the cloud:

Anbox Cloud as a solution developed by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, to bring Android at scale to any cloud with support for ultra low latency video streaming and recent Android versions.


